# Image is cutting at the corners after rotating

Tags: java, image, rotation

I'm facing some problem. As I rotate the image, the image is getting cut at the corners. I'm using the following code for rotating the image. It is rotating properly but getting cut at all of the corners.

```
public static Image rotate(BufferedImage img, double angle) {  
   int w = img.getWidth();    
   int h = img.getHeight();    
   BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());  
   Graphics2D g2 = result.createGraphics();  
   g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
   g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w/2, h/2);
   g2.drawRenderedImage(img, null);
   //g2.drawImage(img,null,0,0);  
   return result;
}
```

I need something that won't allow the corners to be get cut. Please help.

Comment: But what do you want to happen? Do you expect the final `Image` to have the same size as the initial one (so that the rotated image has to be scaled down) or do you expect the drawn image to have (more or less) the initial size as the initial one (so that the `Image` instance has to be bigger than the initial one)?

Comment: The final image should have the same size as that of the initial. My requirement is that the image should get rotated but the look and feel should be the same. But presently the image is getting cut at the corners.

Comment: First, the look and feel has nothing to do with this. Secondly, if the image takes up all the space on a component that is 20 by 40 and you rotate the image by 90 degrees, the image would by 40 by 20 which is too large on the width and this will get cut. You have to either rescale you image or make sure you paint it on a large enough component.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out yourself, the `result` image is too small for the rotated instance. You have to do some math to find the appropriate size. If you are too lazy (=too clever) to do the math yourself, create a `Rectangle2D` matching your original image, create an `AffineTransform` for your rotation, create a transformed shape from your rectangle, and use this shape's bounding box. (You can apply the same transform to your `Graphics` as well.)

Comment: I'm new to this. Can you please help me with some kind of reference or a code snippet. Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you understand *why* your result image is too small. Please check javadoc of AffineTransform on how to get an instance that represents your rotation and how to apply it to shapes. Then follow the steps above.